# how to get the outputs from the embedding layer

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning, keras

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from theano import function

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length = maxlen))
```

I want to get the outputs from the embedding layers. I read through the source in keras but didnt find any suitable function or attribute. Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 8):

You can get the output of any layer, not just an embedding layer, as described [here](http://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-visualize-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer):

```
from keras import backend as K
get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                  [model.layers[3].output])
layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([X])[0]
```

In your case, you would want `model.layers[0].output` instead of `model.layers[3].output`.

Comment: for me get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()],
                                  [model.layers[3].output]) worked.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out what the X means

Comment: In any case thanks for the answers. It showed me the correct way

Comment: @joydeepbhattacharjee Have you figured out what the X is?

Comment: @YanLong I hope so. This happened a long time ago and I dont remember it now. Hopefully I had either figured it out or maybe I used a different approach.

Comment: @joydeepbhattacharjee, from my understanding, the X was one of the input  of your merged layer

Comment: X is a matrix of training cases that you would like to embed.

Comment: That's just regular Python array indexing :)