# Keras: Finding Close Items after Collaborative Filtering

Tags: python-3.x, keras, grouping, recommendation-engine

So I have ran collaborative filtering algorithm using Keras (Tensorflow back-end, if that matters) for a games rating database.

```
def collaborative_filtering(num_items, num_users, num_item_features=50):
    user_in = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int64', name='user_in')
    users_preferences = Embedding(
        #...
        name='users_preferences',
    )(user_in)
    item_in = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int64', name='item_in')
    items_factors = Embedding(
        #...
        name='items_factors',
    )(item_in)

    x = concatenate([users_preferences, items_factors])
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(100, use_bias=True)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(1)(x)

    model = Model([item_in, user_in], x)
    return model
```

Now I have all weights saved in `weights_633-1.79.hdf5` file. I would like to use `items_factors` weights to say which games should be similar one to another. How do I actually go about coding that?

I have found

```
model.load_weights(filepath, by_name=True)
```

function, however, it seems that to use that I'll have to code whole model even though I'm just interested in loading already trained weights.

I have also seen [how to get the outputs from the embedding layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963012/how-to-get-the-outputs-from-the-embedding-layer) and that's what I'm set out to code now, but it seems that there should be more elegant solution.

Comment: have you found any solution to this problem? if yes then could you just show me how to do this.